# mySQL query: SUM/MAX problem

Tags: mysql, sum, max

I am very new to this and having problems with the SUM and MAX in my query:

```
SELECT Score.performerId, Performer.performerName, 
 Performer.countrycode, Country.countryName, Event.eventName, Score.points
FROM Score, Performer, Country,  Event
WHERE points = (SELECT MAX(points) FROM Score 
  WHERE roundName = 'Final') 
AND roundName = 'Final'
AND Score.performerId=Performer.performerId
AND Performer.countryCode=Country.countryCode
AND Score.eventId=Event.eventId
```

I will greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Score.performerId, Performer.performerName, 
    Performer.countrycode, Country.countryName, Event.eventName, Score.points
FROM Score, Performer, Country,  Event,
    (
    SELECT Performer.PerformerId, SUM(score.Points) TotalScore
    FROM Score, Performer, Country,  Event
    WHERE roundName = 'Final'
    AND Score.performerId=Performer.performerId
    AND Performer.countryCode=Country.countryCode
    AND Score.eventId=Event.eventId
    group by Performer.PerformerId
    order by TotalScore Desc
    LIMIT 1
    ) MaxScore
WHERE roundName = 'Final'
AND Score.performerId=Performer.performerId
AND Performer.countryCode=Country.countryCode
AND Score.eventId=Event.eventId
AND Performer.PerformerId=MaxScore.PerformerId
```

I'm a bit lazy to convert to ANSI style joins but you should start looking at using them in preference to the comma notation.